# Track file permissions with Github

Tags: linux, file, github, permissions

I am collaborating with my mates on a project. I am suppose to change the file permissions for certain files in the repository and push to Github. I tried to do this but discovered Github does not track file permissions but just the content of files by default.

My workaround is that, in the project folder, I created a file called `.gitattributes`. In it I add the text * -text. I staged, commited and pushed to github. I think now, I can track the file permission changes. The thing is for the files, say, file3.log the permission change I have made is **-rw-rw----**. I stage this, commited and pushed and pretty much I see the commit message on the file on Github. My mate does a `git pull` and `ls -l file3.log` the permissions he has is **rw-rw-r--** which is not what I want. In fact all the permission changes are not applied as intended.
What do I do to fix this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When I  `chmod` a file and `git push` it, it comes out on another working copy's `git pull` with the new file permissions, as expected. It would also be odd if git lost file meta data like this. Can you please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], i.e., the commands you run?